# Reading from a file showing error in Python

Tags: python

I got the following error.

```
input.writelines(gensim_result)

TypeError: writelines() argument must be a sequence of strings
```

Can any one assist me?

Comment: Please provide more info about `gensim_result`. The error is telling you that this is not a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code line as

```
input.writelines(gensim_result.encode('utf-8'))
```